# Get Id back when using SubSonic SimpleRepository AddMany

Tags: subsonic, batch-file, insert, simplerepository, subsonic-simplerepository

How can I get the Id back to the object when I'm using the AddMany function with SubSonic SimpleRepository. All my objects still get Id=0 when after using it.

```
SimpleRepository repository = new SimpleRepository(ConnectionStringName);
repository.AddMany<T>(insertList);
```

When looking at the source I can see that:

```
public void AddMany<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class, new()
{
    if (_options.Contains(SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations))
    {
        Migrate<T>();
    }

    BatchQuery batch = new BatchQuery(_provider);
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        batch.QueueForTransaction(item.ToInsertQuery(_provider));
    }

    batch.ExecuteTransaction();
}
```

How about making a batch select for latest inserted Id in that table here? Could that ever return the wrong Id? I will write down some code and come back :)

### The actual problem

The problem is that I like to use the inserted Id's in another row (different table) as a fk, maybe there is a way to use batch insert to add two different kinds of rows and set the fk-column to the last inserted id of the other row. A bit complicated there, but I think you get the point:

```
Insert User 
Insert UserAccount -> Set UserAccount.fk_UserId to latest id inserted in User
Insert User 
Insert UserAccount -> Set UserAccount.fk_UserId to latest id inserted in User
```

And so on as a batch.. is that possible?
This could be as much as 10k or more rows times 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved the actual problem:

```
IDataProvider provider = ProviderFactory.GetProvider(connectionStringName);

LogEntry entry1 = CreateEntry("1");
LogEntry entry2 = CreateEntry("2");
LogEntry entry3 = CreateEntry("3");
LogEntry entry4 = CreateEntry("4");

List<LogEntry> items = new List<LogEntry>() { entry1, entry2 };

BatchQuery batch = new BatchQuery();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    QueryCommand cmd = item.ToInsertQuery(provider).GetCommand();
    if (item != items.First())
    {
        cmd.CommandSql = cmd.CommandSql.Replace("@ins_LogEntriesfk_LogEntryId", "@@IDENTITY");
    }
    batch.QueueForTransaction(cmd);
}

batch.ExecuteTransaction();
```

Is this a prefered way on solving the problem. I got another idea, to store all id that's inserted in a table with a GroupId (Guid) and then extract this. There have to be an easier way to extract all inserted Ids on a connection?

Answer (score 1):

I use code like this. This assumes you've cast your batch of objects to a `List`, otherwise use a simple `foreach` on whatever variable you're using:

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope()) {
    thangs.ForEach((t) => {
        t.Id = (int)Repository.Add<Thang>(t);
    });
    ts.Complete();
}
```

`Repository` is the instance of your `SimpleRepository`.

It is using the `TransactionScope` class from [`System.Transactions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) (add reference). As long as your DB supports it, it should work...

Comment: Can this be accomplished with ActiveRecord?